# Xamarin exception - The contract contains synchronous operations, which are not supported

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting pretty strange exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The contract 'ICalculatorService' contains
>   synchronous operations, which are not supported in Silverlight. Split
>   the operations into "Begin" and "End" parts and set the AsyncPattern
>   property on the OperationContractAttribute to 'true'. Note that you do
>   not have to make the same change on the server.

I have simplest WCF service in the world. No async code. Just this:

**Host:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculatorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetSum(int a, int b);
}

public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
{
    public string GetSum(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b).ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri[] addressBase = new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9003/CalculatorService") };
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), addressBase);
        host.Open();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**host config:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MobileWCF.ServerHost.CalculatorService">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8003/CalculatorService" binding="netTcpBinding"
        contract="MobileWCF.Contracts.ICalculatorService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9003/CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="MobileWCF.Contracts.ICalculatorService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

then, I've added Xamarin.Forms (portable) project, added View, and in code-behind in onClickEvent I added:

```
    void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strAddress = "http://localhost:9003/CalculatorService";
        BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(strAddress);

        ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> channel = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>(httpBinding, address);
        var game = channel.CreateChannel(address);
        var num = game.GetSum(3,4);
    }
```

**Why am I getting this exception. Does Xamarin.Forms doesn't allow synchronous services?** Everything should be in Begin/End APM model?

Comment: Your exception msg says silverlight!! Silverlight you have to use AsynPattern = true in operation contract.

Comment: @MKMohanty After changing this I have another exception while newing up ServiceHost: *Additional information: Invalid async Begin method signature for method GetSum in ServiceContract type MobileWCF.Contracts.ICalculatorService. Your begin method must take an AsyncCallback and an object as the last two arguments and return an IAsyncResult.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's see. You're using Xamarin.Forms with a PCL project. The PCL project uses the same profile as Silverlight, and Silverlight doesn't support synchronous methods, hence they're not supported in your app.

If you want to use it, or change the methods to follow the asynchronous patter or change your project type to use a Shared project, the Shared project does not use the portable class profile and can use the full framework.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin says:

> Xamarin.Forms has full support for the Windows Phone 8.1 platform using WinRT. The look and feel of apps using Windows Phone 8.1 support may be different to your earlier Xamarin.Forms Windows Phone apps that were based on **Silverlight**.

All Service Calls in Silverlight are Asynchronous.
For this use:

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
```

For more info see: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101023/Frictionless-WCF-Service-Consumption-in-Silverligh)

Comment: Only this? It still doesn't work. I have exception while newing up ServiceHost: *Additional information: Invalid async Begin method signature for method GetSum in ServiceContract type MobileWCF.Contracts.ICalculatorService. Your begin method must take an AsyncCallback and an object as the last two arguments and return an IAsyncResult.*